# Content of an property dependent on another property value

Tags: jsonschema

I have the following schema, which "works", but does not enforce all the rules required of it.

I get JSON with a series of questions that have a *templateType* and *data* properties. There are different templates for each type, and the type must fit the template (or the client doesn't know how to layout the data).

The schema validates the *templateType* as an enum, and that the data fits one of the templates, but there's no correlation between the type and data structure (e.g. I could get *templateType* yesNo and data structure for multiSelect).

I'd like it to validate that the *templateType* matches the data structure. I can't change the format of the generated JSON, only the schema that validates it. None of the questions I've looked at seem to provide a solution.

For help, the schema can be pasted into the editor at http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/, which generates a form from the schema and JSON data based on selections and data entered into the form.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "question": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Question",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/template"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Question template",
      "required": ["templateType","data"],
      "properties": {
        "templateType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["yesNo","multiSelect"]
        },
        "data": {
          "oneOf": [
            {"$ref": "#/definitions/yesNo"},
            {"$ref": "#/definitions/multiSelect"}
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "yesNo": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Yes/No question",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "label": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "multiSelect": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multi-select question",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Label for option",
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/question"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using `if`, `then`, `else` keywords in your schema? They're part of [JSON Schema draft-07](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html)

It would look like this:

```json
{
  "definitions": {
    "question": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Question",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/template"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Question template",
      "required": ["templateType","data"],
      "properties": {
        "templateType": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": ["yesNo","multiSelect"]
        },
        "data": {
          "if": { "properties": { "templateType": { "pattern": "^yesNo$" } } },
          "then": { "$ref": "#/definitions/yesNo" },
          "else": { "$ref": "#/definitions/multiSelect" }
        }
      }
    },
    "yesNo": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Yes/No question",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "label": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "multiSelect": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multi-select question",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Label for option",
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/question"
  }
}
```

If `if/then/else` isn't supported by your validator, an alternative could be:

```json
{
  "definitions": {
    "question": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Question",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/template"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Question template",
      "required": ["templateType","data"],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "templateType": { "type": "string", "pattern": "yesNo" },
            "data": { "$ref": "#/definitions/yesNo" }
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "templateType": { "type": "string", "pattern": "multiSelect" },
            "data": { "$ref": "#/definitions/multiSelect" }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "yesNo": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Yes/No question",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "label": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "multiSelect": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "Multi-select question",
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Label for option",
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/question"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my validator doesn't support *if..then..else*. I've seen similar questions with solutions involving anyOf + not + required but I can't make them work. There are actually 6 different templates, I've only used 2 here for brevity.

Comment: Ah I see. I have updated my answer to include an alternative solution using `anyOf`. It's a bit verbose I'd admit, perhaps not what you're looking for.

Comment: It would be great if you could include the draft (aka the version) of JSON Schema you are using in your schema. This is both for OP and both proposed solutions.

Comment: Side note: since draft-06 the `additionalProperties: false` to prevent additional properties in object can be safely replaced by `propertyNames : { //enum or pattern here }`.  AFAIK the `propertyNames` schema was specifically introduced for purpose of addressing such a need among all other requirements.

Comment: The tools I'm using ([*JSON editor*](http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/) to generate sample data from schemas and [*jsonvalidate*](http://jsonvalidate.com/) to validate schemas vs data) are based on JSON Schema v4. Your second example works with the validator, but not the editor. I can live with that. I haven't found any good tools for authoring JSON schemas, though there are some OK online validators.